# How can I find pictures in Google Photos in which multiple people that I specify appear together?

Tags: search, google-photos

I know how to use Google Photos to find pictures which have a given person in them, for example showing pictures of "Christopher" or "Michael".

How can I find pictures in Google Photos in which multiple people that I specify appear together, for example, "Christopher" and "Michael" in the same picture?

Comment: did you try `"Christopher" and "Michael"`?

Comment: @user0 that actually works great, even though Google Photos autocomplete doesn't lead one to believe that it _would_ work. Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear that, I shall add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use **`AND`** operator and connect them in a string like:

```
"Christopher" AND "Michael"
```